# Google Chrome profile migration missing FaceBook password and open session on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, migration

I would like to **migrate all my Google Chrome profile** (password, history, open sessions like in FaceBook... etc) from my desktop running Windows 7 to my portable running Windows 7 too.

I have backed up my profile by **copying this directory** to a pendrive:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

but, after transferring it to just the **same directory** (overwriting files) on the portable computer, I have found that FaceBook remembers my login (email) but **doesn't remember my password**.

How could I solve this?

Extra points:

- Google Chrome was **closed when copying** the profile directory on the source machine.
- Google Chrome was **closed when restoring** the profile directory on the destination machine.
- My open **session at FaceBook** (the session was open when I created the backup) is **not remembered**, as long as I have to login again on the destination Chrome.
- I tested **logging in** to FaceBook via http://www.facebook.com and http://www.facebook.es (the spanish domain).
- **%USERPROFILE% differs** on both machines, as long as the user is each `Pepe` on the origin and `Pepito` on destination, so %USERPROFILE% becomes `c:\Users\Pepe` and `c:\Users\Pepito`. This is supposed not to be an issue.

Comment: do you have Gmail account ?

Comment: Look at this Link it might help [link](http://juan2geek.com/how-to-backup-and-restore-entire-google-chrome-setting/)

Comment: Just sync your profiles.

Comment: @Omar: yes, I have some gmail account.

Comment: Usually your settings and bookmarks and passwords are synced with your Gmail account try to log into Gmail and see if it saved in there

Comment: @Omar, I don't have anything synced with the GMail accout. I don't even use Chrome for email. I am just using Chrome as web browser and, as FireFox, it stores passwords, bookmarks, open sessions and so on. I have been able to perform such migrations when needed for Mozilla FireFox by just copying the corresponding directory.